# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module

Tags: java, web, websphere, myeclipse

I am getting the below error when I am running the application.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
```

Even I put the below jar files in my class path and still there is no luck on running the application.
Jars that I put:
jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar
jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.7.4.jar
jackson-jarxrs-base-2.7.4.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations.jar

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which release of MyEclipse you're using but you probably need to ensure that those jars are also added to the Deployment Assembly. Search for Deployment Assembly in the Preferences (the location changed in MyEclipse 2017). That preferences page has the option of adding missing jars from your build path. Instead of altering the build path, in future, alter the deployment assembly and this will update the build path.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I am using MyEclipse Blue Edition 2016.